# Reds_r not recognised as a valid RGBA argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I used the tips dataframe already present in pandas.
The followng code only showed the regplot but the violinplot failed due to an error

**CODE**:

```
fig, (axis1,axis2) = plt.subplots(1,2,sharey =True)

sns.regplot("total_bill","tip_pect",tips,ax=axis1)
sns.violinplot(tips['tip_pect'],tips['size'],color='Reds_r',ax=axis2)
```

**ERROR**:

```
Invalid RGBA argument: 'Reds_r'
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be the `palette` parameter:

```
color='Reds_r'
```

should be

```
palette='Reds_r'
```

Comment: But still the violin plot is not visible properly